# How to initialize values inside nested json struct in GO?

Tags: json, go, data-structures

I have this struct right now

```
type ServiceStruct struct {
      Name     string `json:"name"`
      DataStruct struct {
          ID    string `json:"id"`
          Size  string `json:"size"`
     }
}
```

But im not sure how to assign values to the elements inside this struct. Specially the DataStruct inside the ServiceStruct

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an anonymous struct literal (which requires copy-pasting the type of `DataStruct`) or assign values to individual fields using `=`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ServiceStruct struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    DataStruct struct {
        ID   string `json:"id"`
        Size string `json:"size"`
    }
}

func main() {
    s1 := ServiceStruct{
        Name: "foo",
        DataStruct: struct {
            ID   string `json:"id"`
            Size string `json:"size"`
        }{
            ID:   "bar",
            Size: "100",
        },
    }

    s2 := ServiceStruct{
        Name: "foo",
    }
    s2.DataStruct.ID = "bar"
    s2.DataStruct.Size = "100"

    fmt.Println(s1)
    fmt.Println(s2)

    // Output:
    // {foo {bar 100}}
    // {foo {bar 100}}
}
```

Alternatively, consider giving the type of `DataStruct` a name so you can refer to it in the struct literal instead of copy-pasting (which is not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/GObadB9WyN

Example of passing/unmarshaling a JSON into your struct. This has been my primary use-case, I hope it is helpful.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type ServiceStruct struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    DataStruct struct {
        ID    string `json:"id"`
        Size  string `json:"size"`
    }
}

func main() {
    x := `{
        "Name": "Fido",
        "DataStruct": {
            "ID": "Dog",
            "Size": "Small"
        }
    }`

    ex := ServiceStruct{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &ex)

    fmt.Println(ex.Name)
}
```